# menu test spread and wrapper correction

Tags: css, menu, navigation

Please see this: http://i.imgfst.com/z6BSBf.jpg
so you can see i have problem with the nav menu. i dont know how to centre the navigation wrapper so it is shorter on the right side (to match left side) also how to make more space between text menu as it looks a bit squished at the moment..

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <div id="nav">{menu}</div>
</div>

#nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0 20;
    padding: 0 4px 10px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 5 ;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #B31717;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav {
    vertical-align:center;
}    

#nav > ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.wsite-menu-default a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .90);
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.wsite-menu-default a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .90);
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: post also your html-code

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle? Always much easier for us to work with :)